# Получение query параметра из NextJS NextApiRequest

Tags: typescript, next.js

Как достать `query` из GET запроса в NextJS?

route.ts:

```
import { NextApiRequest } from 'next'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'



export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest) {
    console.log(req.query)
    return NextResponse.json([
        {
            name: "1",
            value: 1
        },
        {
            name: "2",
            value: 2
        },

    ])
}
```

Отправляю `http://localhost:3000/api/support/getNewTableData?login=userlogin`

В консоли получаю: `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Решено

```
    import { NextApiRequest } from 'next'
    import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
    
    export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest) {
        let login = null
        if (req.url) {
            const url = new URL(req.url)
            login = url.searchParams.get("login")
        }
        return NextResponse.json({
            login: login
        })
    }
```